# Azure AD access token does not contain groups claim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using curl command to get access token, i'm able to get access token using curl command with client credentials.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={secret}' https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tentant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

But the Access token does not contain group claims.

How to get groups in the access token..? any help is appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Siddu, IMO, the group claims should be enabled on the resource application for which the token is being issued. In the above request, the client app being authenticated, is like an app account. Based on above request, you are using v1 `/token` endpoint - where default resource is: `Windows Azure Active Directory`. My suggestion would be to use v2 `/token` endpoint and set the scope parameter explicitly to define the resource app. The resource app should be enabled with the required group claim configuration to be passed in the authenticating identity's token.

Comment: i have tried using `v2/token` still same issue, not getting any groups claims

Answer (score 1):

include the scope in the token request with the value as api://4564664-534d-441b-8270-4654446564/user_impersonation (sample)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [this document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups#steps-to-enable-this-option-in-your-app)

> If you are exposing a Web API using the Expose an API option, then you
> can also choose the Group ID option under the Access section.

So, when you add groups claims in `Token configuration` blade, you need to pick "group id" in "Access"

[image]

And you also need to check the manifest file of the azure ad app in azure portal, if the `groupMembershipClaims` claim has null vaule, you may set it to `All` ,see [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#groupmembershipclaims-attribute).

If you need to add groups for your azure ad app, go to azure ad -> Enterprise Applications -> find your app -> users and groups

[image]

Then you need to "expose an api", follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis), then you need to add the api permission in your azure ad application which used to generate access token.

The screenshot below is an access token generated by ropc flow. But actually, I test with client credential flow, I can't get `groups` claim. In my opinion, this is because client credential flow is not related to a user, even user groups.

[image]

Comment: My requirement is to get groups claim in the access token. We have service account and will be using same service account credentials for getting access token. So need to get groups claims in the access token

Comment: Hi Siddu, as I mentioned in my comment above, just trying to verify: Are you adding the group claim configuration on the app corresponding to the service account used for logging in OR are you adding the group claim settings on the resource app for which you are getting the token (i.e., the scope claim for v2 API)? I did a PoC and it does work for client-credentials workflow when group setting is enabled on the "resource app".

Comment: @Sidduh can't you see the `groups` claim in my screenshot above? That's decoded from an access token which generated from ROPC flow. Or I misunderstood in some place?

Comment: @ChintanRajvir, I have added group claims on the app ( azure ad -> Enterprise Applications -> find your app -> users and groups). and i'm using client credentials to get an access token but still i can't see groups in Access Token.

Comment: @TinyWang is there anything specific that should be done with that "Expose an API" part? The article you've linked says nothing about it.

Comment: `expose an API` is used for generating an access token which containing the API we exposed. not very sure about what you are concerning now. for `expose an API`, it only needs to follow the artical I shared... Feel free to share your requirements, you can also create a new question to get more concerns.